# Quando instalo o apk ele está instalando mais de uma vez o app

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

estou usando o Android Studio, enquanto rodo o emular pra instalar o apk, durante a instalação ocorre de instalar mais de uma vez o app, ficando dois ícones (dois apps). Como resolver isto?

Comment: Não seira melhor desinstalar a aplicação via 'ADB'?

Comment: É só apagar o aplicativo.

Comment: Faça titulos e perguntas mais claras, veja como outras pessoas (com mais experiencia) fazem as perguntas, assim facilita a responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi certo, quando se instala o .apk, ele cria dois Apps,

Isto ocorre pois deve haver duas Activity's setadas como `MAIN`

Verifique se em seu `AndroidManifest` as Activity's com o seguinte `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Obrigado consegui resolver meu problema era isto mesmo....vlw

Answer (score 0):

Execute no terminal:

```
adb uninstall br.com.seuapp
```

Depois, faça o *deploy* normalmente.